# How to update an object on Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, parse-server

I am trying to update an object that's already in a class on Parse, however, although there's no error, the object is not being updated.
That's the code I have.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Requests")
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: request.username)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error finding a request")
    } else {
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(object.objectId!, block: {(object:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error getting object a request")
                    } else if let object = object{
                        //upadate db
                        object["response"] = "True"
                        object.saveInBackground()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: try instead of saveInBackground use        object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
            } else {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

Comment: @stosha thank you. I tried to do what you said but the same thing happens. There's no error but the object still doesn't get updated.

Comment: in your case you can change and save object directly without query.getObjectInBackground.... I think so. Instead of query.getObjectInBackground... try to object["response"] = "True" and then save.

Comment: The object that you are trying to update is secured by ACL or it's public ?